# Is it correct? $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{c^{n}}{n!^{\frac{1}{k}}}$

Tags: limits, natural-numbers

This is what we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{c^{n}}{n!^{\frac{1}{k}}},$$
$$n \in N, k>0, c>0$$
If n->inf
$$\frac{{x}_{n+1}}{{x}_{n}}=\frac{{c}^{n+1}}{{(n+1)!}^{\frac{1}{k}}}*\frac{{n!}^{\frac{1}{k}}}{{c}^{n}}=\frac{c}{{(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{k}}}<1$$
obviously$${x}_{n}>0$$
This means, that we have a limit; let it be 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {x}_{n}=a$$
$${x}_{n+1}=\frac{c}{{(n+1)}^{\frac{1}{k}}}*{x}_{n}$$
$$a=0*a$$
this means that $$a=0$$

am i right?

Comment: Looks well to me.